# std::vector, constructors, objects

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, constructor, vector

The folowing constructor

```
 std::vector<Object> objects(n);
```

creates n objects calling the default constructor, i.e. something like that:

```
std::vector <Object> objects;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) objects.push_back(o);
```

Is this procedure also valid for dynamically allocated objects? Does the construction

```
std::vector<Object *> objects(n);
```

represent this functionality?

```
std::vector <Object*> objects;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) objects.push_back(new Object());
```

If not, is there a way how to arrange it?

Comment: Only for note: is something like that except that each `push_back()` reallocates the vector's internal buffer. Constructing a `vector` passing the number of elements the buffer is allocated once.

Answer (score 6):

```
std::vector<Object> objects(n);
```

The behavior of this depends on which version of the C++ Standard your Standard Library implementation implements:

- In C++03, this creates one default constructed `Object` and then copy constructs that object n times.
- In C++0x, this default constructs n `Object`s.

The difference shouldn't usually matter, but it's good to know.

---

```
std::vector<Object *> objects(n);
```

This creates a `vector` with n null `Object*`s in it.  Since `Object*` is not a class type and does not have a constructor, the newly inserted objects are value initialized, which for pointers means they are set to `NULL`.

If you want to dynamically create new objects and then store pointers to them in the container, you need to call `new` yourself.  Note that you should not be storing raw pointers in a standard library container if the container owns the pointed-to objects.  Doing so is not exception safe.

You should be using a smart pointer like `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` instead  (note:  the `auto_ptr` smart pointer cannot be stored in containers due to its unusual copy semantics, thus `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` should be used).

In any case, to insert pointers to n distinct, dynamically allocated objects into the container, you need to call `new` n times to create those n objects.  There's nothing wrong with your `for` loop solution.

Comment: An example where it does matter is `struct dumb { int i; dumb() { static int j = 0; i = j++; } }; int main(void) { std::vector<dumb> v(2); std::cout << v[1].i << std::endl; }` which will print 0 in C++03 but 1 in C++0x.

Answer (score 2):

> The folowing constructor

```
std::vector<Object> objects(n);
```

> creates n objects calling the default constructor

Yes, but the default constructor is used only to construct the second optional parameter to the constructor of `vector`, the `n` objects in the vector are constructed by copying this parameter. [C++03 answer]

If you did something like:

```
std::vector<Object*> objects(n, new Object());
```

you would dynamically allocate one object and have `n` pointers to that object in your `vector` which is probably not what you want.

It is almost always a bad idea to use a container of pointers if that container is supposed to own the dynamically allocated objects. You should consider something like `boost::ptr_vector`, or if that is not possible a container of smart pointers (not `std::auto_ptr`, though).

Answer (score 0):

Your final code example has the right general idea, but tread carefully: `vector` will *not* manage the allocations for you if you do that!  `objects.clear()` will leak memory, for instance.

You probably want to use `std::vector<some_smart_ptr<Object> >` instead, but choosing the right smart pointer class requires care and attention to (for instance) what happens when you copy elements from one vector to another.  [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) is a safe choice, but may have unnecessary overhead for your use case.  [`boost::ptr_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) may be better.

Comment: The `vector` won't do any allocation at all, the pointers will be value-initialized to null.

Comment: The OP's final code example (creating the vector and then calling `new` and `push_back` in a loop) clearly indicates that they are aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

No, the `vector` won't be automatically created with pointers to `Object` instances.  You will have to perform the `for` loop you have written in order to populate it correctly.

You will also need to `delete` each of these objects when you have finished with them too.